# How to compile FFProbe as stand-alone application? (Mac/Linux/Win)

Tags: linux, windows, macos, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm trying to compile FFMPEG (I'm actually only looking for FFProbe, which is included in the FFMPEG tools) as a standalone application for MacOS X, Linux and possibly Windows.
With standalone I mean that the libraries (x264, OpenJPEG, etc) are "embedded" into the executable so that I have to distribute only one executable for FFProbe - I apologize that I don't know the proper lingo for this (please let me know), I'm a newbie when it comes to this.

I have started by trying to do this under MacOS X, without any luck, but plan to do this for Linux and MacOS X as well.

I did see a few pre-compiled binaries that do this, and do not depend on extra libraries, but the versions I have found so far are either not the current version (1.x) or do not included the libraries in the executable ([evermeet](http://www.evermeet.cx/ffprobe/)).

I followed several guides (for example: [FFMpeg MacOSX Compilation Guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide), [reneVolution](http://www.renevolution.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x/)), with or without the use of Brew, but none of these show me how to embed the libraries in the executable.
I assume this is an option to be set for linking.

I'm not sure if it's appropriate to ask this question for Win, Mac and Linux at the same time - if it's not appropriate: I'd like to start with doing this for the Mac version.

My system runs MacOS X 10.9, XCode 5.0.2, with commandline tools and brew installed. I'm only looking for an Intel binary, so not a universal or PowerPC binary.

For Windows I can use either Windows 8.1 or XP, for Linux I currently use Ubuntu 12, all of which are virtual machines.

Comment: Static build of `ffprobe` for Linux is available at http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: Static build of `ffprobe` for OS X is available at http://www.evermeet.cx/ffprobe/snapshots/

Comment: Is "Static" the right way to say this?

Comment: The builds from evermeet.cx crash (Illegal instruction: 4), I did try those before. One of the reason why I started digging in compiling it myself. :(

Comment: Static Linux build at johnvansickle.com are 64 bit only. Would a 32 bit version run on a 64 bit Linux distro? Or is it "safe" to assume taht most users run 64 bit? (I'm not too familiar with Linux and what versions are commonly used)

Comment: 32 bit should work for both.

Comment: After some more experimenting with the pre-compiled versions of evermeet, I did find that the error is actually caused by Entropy (the app that I use to extract the compressed 7z file). Double click results in a "damaged" executable. Opening the archive and dragging the executable to the Finder results in a perfectly fine executable. This however still doesn't tell me how to compile ffmpeg/ffprobe myself :(

Comment: I used a static build of ffprobe for OSX as per LordNeckbead's answer and it worked for me. Thanks again LordNeckbeard. All I did was download a build, unzip it, move it to a directory in your `$PATH` variable (such as `/usr/bin/ffprobe` since that's where I had compiled ffmpeg to before and it worked. )

Answer (score 1):

You need to install FFProbe with all the options, like in mac

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libass --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openjpeg --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-schroedinger --with-speex --with-theora --with-tools
```